# Dynamic minDate for datepicker

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I'm trying to cause my Datepicker to set its minimum date dynamically based on value chosen from List of Values. To be specific I have a club that has a date of creation. Based on that I want to create a member of that club, but after choosing to which club I want to add that member I want the minDate value of the Datepicker to be set as the day of creation of that specific club (for example I choose a club that was created 31/08/99 so the datepicker's minDate should be that date). Will be grateful for any help.
(I've tried getting the date and assinging it to a hidden item in order to reference it but the only thing I achieved is all dates being blocked. Don't know if that's an issue with the solution or maybe with the return value of sql query that returns the date. I also could't find any documentation regarding Datepicker to understand what can be typed in the Minimum/Maximum Date attribute-fields)

Comment: How dynamic does the solution need to be? It sounds like you create a club first, then add members on a separate page/form. Is that correct? If so, the implementation would be simpler than if you were able to choose/edit the "club created date" on the same page as the "member added date".

Answer (score 2):

[image: Datepicker Minimum Date]

You can reference a page item for minimum date. 
Getting the date and writing it to an hidden item was the correct first step.
You can utilize a dynamic action on change of your Select List (LoV) which sets the clubs creation date for the hidden item (make sure to utilize correct Dateformat here, this needs to be the same as your datepickers)

[image: Dynamic ACtion]

Make sure to add the hidden item to "Items to return" so its value is saved.
[image: PL/SQL Code]

Add a 2nd true action which refreshed your datepicker item
[image: refresh datepicker]

Comment: So that's more or less what I've been trying to do. Now I did it again reffering to your tips. To see whether I get my date correctly I set up the additional field into 'Display Only' mode and it seems to work - I get the correct date in correct format but the datepicker that was supposed to be affected, isn't at all. As if the refresh action did nothing. Do actions inside one Dynamic Action get triggered sequentially or concurrently? Tell me if you need any screenshots.